# Is there a hot key to delete one message from a conversation thread in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

Is there a hot key to delete one message from a conversation thread in Gmail?

It is convenient to delete email by using `#`, but it doesn't delete one message from a conversation thread?

See https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=7401 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look possible right now to delete a single message using a hotkey.

The most promising route seems to be to create a [custom Gmail hotkey](http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/custom_keyboard.htm), but the current **Custom Keyboard Shortcut** from the Google Labs doesn't support the delete single message command that you're looking for. You may want to try to petition the creator of the Lab to add that command as an option - there's a **[Send Feedback](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/request.py?contact_type=labs&selected=custom_keyboard)** link.